# inserting contents of one text file into another in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I would like to insert the contents of one text file (with newlines) into another at a predetermined location (after some string):
I tried the following:
the base file:

```
cat base
ONE
TWO
THREE
```

the extension:

```
cat ext
100
200
300
400
500
600
700
800
900
A00
B00
C00
D00
```

and the script I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
ext=$(<ext)
sed -i "s/TWO/TWO\n$ext/" base
```

which gives me **sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to **ed**it a file directly, I always suggest `ed` instead of the non-standard `sed -i` (Where different implementions of `sed` that do support it act differently, a common source of questions here):

```
printf "%s\n" "/TWO/r ext" w | ed -s base
```

will insert the contents of file ext after the first line containing TWO in base, and then **w**rite the new version of base back to disk.

If you *must* use `sed`, the proper invocation will look very similar (No surprise since they're sibling commands):

```sh
sed -i '/TWO/r ext' base
```

(This will insert the ext file after *every* TWO in base, though, not just the first.)

The key in both is the `r` command, which **r**eads the contents of the given file and inserts it after a line with the matching address. Works a lot better than trying to read the file contents into a variable and including the text directly in the `ed`/`sed` commands.

---

If you want to insert the contents of a variable after the line, you can use

```
printf "%s\n" "/TWO/a" "$ext" . w | ed -s base
```

(As long as the variable doesn't have a line with just a period)

or with GNU sed

```
sed -i "/TWO/a ${ext//$'\n'/\\\n}" base
```

to **a**ppend text after the addressed line.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer given by Shawn shows a possible solution, it does not explain why your attempt did not work.

Note that your variable `ext` contains line feed characters. Hence, sed sees here a physical line feed. You would get the same error message when typing on the command line (in **two** lines):

```
sed -i "s/TWO/TWO\nfoo
/" base
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '0,/TWO/{/TWO/r extFile' -e '}' baseFile
```

This will place the file `extFile` after the first occurrence of the string `TWO`. The `-i` option may be used to amend the file in place.

An alternative solution:

```
sed -e '/TWO/!b;r extFile' -e ':a;n;ba' baseFile
```

N.B. The use of the `-e` option to split the commands after the `r filename` command. The `r` must be followed by a newline and the `-e` simulates this on a single line.

If you want to insert the file after each occurrence of the string `TWO`, then just use (as Shawn has already explained):

```
sed '/TWO/r extFile' baseFile
```